# Combine Two Arrays with numerical keys without overwriting the old keys

Tags: php, arrays

I don't want to use array_merge() <strike>as it results in</strike> i misunderstood that  all values with the same keys would be overwritten. i have two arrays

```
$array1 = array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar');
$array2 = array(0=>'bar', 1=>'foo');
```

and would like to combine them resulting like this

```
array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar',2=>'bar', 3=>'foo');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) *appends* the values of the second array to the first. It does not overwrite keys.

Your example, results in:

> Array (
>       [0] => foo
>       [1] => bar
>       [2] => bar
>       [3] => foo )

However, `If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.`

Unless this was just an example to another problem you were having?

Comment: Whoops, I only read the manual and misse that bit, only kept reading things would overwrite

Answer (score 5):

If someone stumbles upon this, this is a way to do it nowadays:

```
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

Comment: was about to log-in and post the same

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?  I'm not sure *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish, but from your description it sounds like this will work:

```
$array1 = array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar');
$array2 = array(0=>'bar', 1=>'foo');

foreach ($array2 as $i) {
    $array1[] = $i;
}

echo var_dump($array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably much better ways but what about:

```
 $newarray= array();
    $array1 = array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar');
    $array2 = array(0=>'bar', 1=>'foo');

    $dataarrays = array($array1, $array2);

    foreach($dataarrays as $dataarray) {
        foreach($dataarray as $data) {
            $newarray[] = $data;
        }
    }

 print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_keys(array_merge(array_flip($array1), array_flip($array2)));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I know this is a bit late ;-) but this solution does not work for OP.

Comment: hellow. what do you mean? could you give an example?

Comment: Have you tested your code against OP's arrays? I don't get the expected result. Did you get that?  Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => bar [3] => foo )