# Add array to an array with the same indexes not being merged

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine Two Arrays with numerical keys without overwriting the old keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176541/combine-two-arrays-with-numerical-keys-without-overwriting-the-old-keys)

OK guys, was searching about this one with no luck - it always points only to `array_merge` or `array_push` or `array_combine` functions which are useless for my purpose.

Here are two arrays (number indexed):

```
Array (
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => "asdvsdfsasdfsdf"
    [2] => "sdgvsdfgsdfbsdf"
)
Array (
    [0] => 25485
    [1] => "tyjfhgdfsasdfsdf"
    [2] => "mojsbnvgsdfbsdf"
)
```

and I need to create one "joined" (unioned) array, so it will look like:

```
Array (
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => "asdvsdfsasdfsdf"
    [2] => "sdgvsdfgsdfbsdf"
    [3] => 25485
    [4] => "tyjfhgdfsasdfsdf"
    [5] => "mojsbnvgsdfbsdf"
)
```

As I found nothing on this problem I tried by myself ($arr1 and $arr2 are the two small arrays):

```php
$result_array = $arr1;
foreach($arr2 as $v) {
    $result_array[] = $v;
}
```

This is, of course, working fine but I don't like this approach - imagine the situation when there will not be just 3 elements in second array...

**Question**: is there a better approach or at the best some built-in function (I do not know about)???

Comment: [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) should work just fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array merge works fine for your numerically indexed arrays:

```
<?php

$arrayOne = array(
     0 => 12345
    ,1 => "asdvsdfsasdfsdf"
    ,2 => "sdgvsdfgsdfbsdf"
);
$arrayTwo =  array(
     0 => 25485
    ,1 => "tyjfhgdfsasdfsdf"
    ,2 => "mojsbnvgsdfbsdf"
);


$arrayMerged = array_merge($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);

print_r($arrayMerged);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => asdvsdfsasdfsdf
    [2] => sdgvsdfgsdfbsdf
    [3] => 25485
    [4] => tyjfhgdfsasdfsdf
    [5] => mojsbnvgsdfbsdf
)
```

Comment: Jee, didn't read the whole sentence and omitted the `string keys` words so I was supposing that the same indexes will always be overwritten... Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will work without any problem as your using numeric keys ... see the explanation below from the docs

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. **If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended**.

emphasis mine

Comment: Jee, didn't read the whole sentence and omitted the `string keys` words so I was supposing that the same indexes will always be overwritten... Thanks.